# How does sizeof work? How can I write my own?

Tags: c++

I know C++ and know the function `sizeof` itself but I need to write my own sizeof function so please explain how it works exactly? What does it do with the parameter?

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, it's a special operator that maps types to integers at compile time.

Comment: ok and how implement it by function such that do the same job as  sizeof?

Comment: @davit the answer is you *can't*, at least not without making use of the existing `sizeof`. It's not something that can be done at runtime.

Comment: @davit What are you actually trying to achieve here?  What will your version of sizeof do, and why?

Comment: I don't buy the "you can't" answers. There's always some hack you can come up with. The issue is, why the hell you would want to reimplement sizeof... Homework? To gain a better understanding?

Comment: @davit If you really want to figure what's going on internally, why not try and see what something like int i = sizeof(int); gets mapped to in assembly (gcc -S <filename.c> & then look into filename.s).

Comment: @Ates Goral:  Any hack you can come up with (like pointer arithmetic, or declaring an array and examining the contents) uses `sizeof` internally.  Fundamentally, you can't extract information that isn't there.  `sizeof` is based on symbol table information which is part of compilation and is normally discarded afterwards.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to reimplement sizeof? While that is not possible exactly, there may be workarounds that achieve your goal.

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: Why would you want to create "function such that do the same job as sizeof"!?  If it does the same job it is pointless (and less efficient since it would do it at runtime, not compile time).  An object only has one size, you do not need to reimplement this.  Answer the counter-questions and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.  There is probably a better and more practical solution that the impossible one you are thinking of.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You haven't provided any meaningful details about what it is you want to do, so it is hard to figure out what you need.

You can "wrap" `sizeof` by you own template function like

```
template <typename T> size_t my_sizeof() {
  return sizeof(T);
}
```

and then use it as

```
size_t s = my_sizeof<int>();
```

From time to time one can come across a request to implement sizeof-like functionality *without* using `sizeof`. Requests like that make no practical sense whatsoever, yet sometimes are used as homework assignments. One can probably do it as follows

```
template <typename T> size_t my_sizeof() {
  T t;
  return (char *) (&t + 1) - (char *) &t;
}
```

which would require a default-constructible `T`. A less restricting but formally illegal solution (a hack) would be something like

```
template <typename T> size_t my_sizeof() {
  return (char *) ((T *) NULL + 1) - (char *) (T *) NULL;
}
```

The above implementations implement type-based `sizeof`.

An attempt to emulate the functionality of value-based `sizeof` might look as follows

```
template <typename T> size_t my_sizeof(const T& obj) { 
  return my_sizeof<T>();
}
```

but this will not be even remotely equivalent to the built-in `sizeof`, at least because the built-in `sizeof` does not evaluate its argument.

Finally, neither of these implementations will produce integral constant expressions (ICE), as the built-in `sizeof` does. Producing an ICE that way is impossible to achieve in the current version of the language.

In any case this all, of course, is totally devoid of any practical value. Just use `sizeof` when you want to know the size.

Comment: Of course the fact that this works is completely dependent on the compile-time invariant `sizeof(char) == 1`, which is a bit of a catch-22.

Comment: Well, the size `sizeof` returns is measured in "char sizes", since in C/C++ terminology char is byte and byte is char.

Comment: @AndreyT : The size of `char` is 2 on some systems. This is not a constant defined by C.

Comment: @kbok: Incorrect. In C language `sizeof(char)` is always exactly 1. It *is* a constant defined by C. If on some system `char` occupies more than 1 machine byte, that only means that from C language point of view each C-byte will consist of several machine bytes. And `sizeof(char)` will still be exactly 1. In other words, `sizeof` in C evaluates to the object/type size in `char`s, so no matter what `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: +1, @AndreyT.  In C and C++, `char` is always 1 byte.  That doesn't mean it's 8 bits, but it *is* always 1 byte, hence `sizeof(char) == 1` is always true.

Comment: @AndreyT, how to write myown function to find the size of a class object?

Answer (score 32):

`sizeof` is a compiler built-in operator. It is evaluated at compile-time by the compiler, and there is no runtime code behind it. You cannot write your own.

Asking this is akin to asking how you would write your own version of `return`.

Comment: You can, however, create a *wrapper* for `sizeof`, which might be what the OP needs. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: His confusion is understandable, since you *can* override new/delete.

Comment: Is it possible to write your own version of `return` then?

Comment: @pindatjuh If you're serious, no. Although much like AndreyT's answer, there are silly tricks that could give the same effect, such as inline assembly or abuse of `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

Answer (score 7):

A non-portable way to write your own sizeof() function is to take advantage of how stack-based variables are often laid out in memory:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int mysizeof(T)
{
  T temp1;
  T temp2;

  return (int)&temp1 - (int)&temp2;
}

int main()
{
  cout << "sizeof mysizeof" << endl;

  char c = 0; short s = 0; int i = 0; long l = 0;
  float f = 0; double d = 0; long double ld = 0;

  cout << "char: " << mysizeof(c) << endl;
  cout << "short: " << mysizeof(s) << endl;
  cout << "int: " << mysizeof(i) << endl;
  cout << "long: " << mysizeof(l) << endl;
  cout << "float: " << mysizeof(f) << endl;
  cout << "double: " << mysizeof(d) << endl;
  cout << "long double: " << mysizeof(ld) << endl;
}
```

[See it in action.](http://codepad.org/KepUXN40)
[A 0-parameter version.](http://codepad.org/lyn5AAay)
[A version that uses one array instead of two variables.](http://codepad.org/nz9Jbqet)

Warning: This was a fun puzzle, but you should never use this in real code.  `sizeof` is guaranteed to work.  This is not.  Just because it works on this version of this compiler for this platform does not mean it will work for any other.

The real operator takes advantage of being a part of the compiler.  Sizeof knows how big each type of variable is because it has to know.  If the compiler doesn't know how big each type is, it wouldn't be able to lay your program out in memory.

Edit: Note that all of these flawed examples rely on the original `sizeof` operator.  It's used to space the stack variables, and to create and index array variables.

Comment: It'd probably be safer to have an array of two items, rather than counting on the compiler to put locals in a given order.  array[1] always comes after array[0], and with the proper padding.

Comment: @dash: I thought about that too, but got distracted.  I've updated my answer with a link to an array-based implementation.

Comment: Neither implementation works on an abstract class or a class lacking a public, zero parameter constructor either.

Comment: @jmuc: Good points!  I only tested on built-in types, and just for the exercise.

Comment: How about something like `return int(&((T*)0)[1])`?  Still need the complete type to be available (as you do for sizeof), but at least you don't need to build it.

Comment: @dash: That works: http://codepad.org/NgwP4x1A .  Of course, array indexing uses sizeof implicitly, but then, so does layout variables in memory.

Answer (score 4):

As already said it is an operator not a function, but additionally it is one of the operators for which operator overloading is not allowed:

[Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ: Why can't I overload dot, ::, sizeof, etc.?](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot)

I can think of no conceivable reason why you would want to overload this in any case.  If you have an class for which size information other than that which `sizeof` yields is required, then simply add a member function to provide that information; as for example in `std::string:size()` which returns the length of the string managed by the object rather than the size of the object which is semantically different; you do not want to monkey with the semantics of `sizeof`!

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is an C++ operator which yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. Result of `sizeof` is an implementation-defined constant of type `size_t`, but should meet the requirements set forth in C++ Standard 5.3.3. You could write your own type traits that will work similar to  built-in `sizeof` operator.

```
template<typename T> struct get_sizeof;

template<> struct get_sizeof<char>          { static const size_t value = 1; };
template<> struct get_sizeof<unsigned char> { static const size_t value = 1; };
template<> struct get_sizeof<int>           { static const size_t value = 4; };
template<> struct get_sizeof<long>          { static const size_t value = 4; };
// etc.

...
// sample of use
static const size_t size = get_sizeof<int>::value;
char x[get_sizeof<int>::value];
```

But this have no sense since only creators of the compiler are knows actual values of `value` for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` isn't a function, and you can't write your own version. The compiler works out the type of the argument (unless it's already a type), then substitutes the expression with an integer constant.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this post when searching for a way to get the same functionality as the sizeof operator. It turned out that I implemented a function called bit_sizeof() that looks a lot like the operator sizeof, but which returns the number of bits of a given type instead. I implemented a global template function like this:

```
#include <limits.h>   //For CHAR_BIT

//Global function bit_sizeof()
template<typename TSizeOfType>
constexpr uint32_t bit_sizeof(TSizeOfType)
{
   return (sizeof(TSizeOfType) * CHAR_BIT);
}
```

This function requires the use of the c++11 standard, as it uses the keyword constexpr. Without the keyword constexpr, the function will compile still. But the compiler may not optimize properly and put in a function call at each call site of using the bit_sizeof function. With the use of constexpr, the whole function evaluates to a constant, which in my knowledge should be exactly equivalent to how the sizeof operator works? Correct me if I am wrong. In use I call the function like this, with an added parantesis after the type:

```
uint32_t uiBitsInType = bit_sizeof(char());
```

The function can be useful when creating bit masks for example:

```
uint32_t uiMask = (((uint32_t(0x1) << bit_sizeof(char())) - 0x1) << bit_sizeof(char()));
```

Which could be more readable than this:

```
uint32_t uiMask2 = (((uint32_t(0x1) << (sizeof(char) * 0x8)) - 0x1) << (sizeof(char) * 0x8));
```

Personally I have other uses for this function also.

Comment: You might want to check out `CHAR_BIT`. Also, `_T` is a prefix reserved for implementation-defined names. Just drop the `_`, C++ templates are not macros. They obey scope, so `typename TSizeOfType` is visible only inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

If he wants to write his own sizeof he just needs to grab the source code of a C++ compiler and go ahead. The source will also show how sizeof can be implemented.

Comment: It would probably be implemented using compiler-internal data structures that couldn't be accessed via the C++ source.

Comment: You misunderstood me. My advice was to create a modified compiler from an existing compiler source. This can be very educational.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time ([Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) and [Loki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_%28C%2B%2B%29) make use of it). So, I think, it is impossible to write sizeof - complain function for dynamically allocated buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` isn't a function. It's an operator in C.
We can implement its functionality something like follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define mysizeof(X)  \

           ({                    \
                  __typeof(X) x;  \
                  (char *) (&x+1) - (char*) (&x); \
           })
int main()
{

     struct sample
     {
         int a;float b; char c;
     };

     printf("%d", mysizeof(struct sample));
     return 0;
}
```

Answer : 12